# React-Router rerenders my component from useEffect, how to mitigate this?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux, react-router

I have a `useEffect()` in my App component, that checks if there is a locally stored user in local storage, and if there is, it updates with dispatch my redux state with the information.
This is extremely problematic, because when a person goes to my route `player/example`, my App component renders the `Player` component, and then when the user state updates from `useEffect`, it renders the `Player` component on the route again. Thus running the component twice, and any `useEffects` inside my `Player` component like fetching data, calls data twice!

Is there absolutely anyway to fix this or am I doing my functionality wrong. Its driving me nuts

To sum up, basically the `Player` component gets rendered twice, because initially the App renders it when there is no user, and when a user is found from the useEffect, it renders it again, even though you stay on the same page with the url `player/example`

```
   // React 
    import { useEffect } from 'react'
    
    // Redux
    import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
    
    // React Reducer
    import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom"
    import { loginUser, logoutUser } from './reducers/user';
    
    // Components
    import Login from './components/Login';
    import Player from './components/Player';
    
    function App() {
      console.log("app component")
      const dispatch = useDispatch()
      const user = useSelector(state => state.user)
    
      useEffect(() => {
        const loggedUserJSON = window.localStorage.getItem('loggedUser')
        if (loggedUserJSON) {
          const user= JSON.parse(loggedUserJSON)
          dispatch(loginUser(user))
        }
      }, [])
    
      // User not logged in
      if (!user) { 
        return (
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/login" element={<Login/>}/>
            <Route path="/" element={<Login/>} />
            <Route path="/player/:username" element={<Player/>}/> 
          </Routes>
        )
      }
      
      // User logged in
      return (
        <div>
          <h1><button onClick={() => dispatch(logoutUser())}>LOG OUT</button></h1>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/login" element={<h1>HOME</h1>}/>
            <Route path="/" element={<h1>HOME</h1>} />
            <Route path="/player/:username" element={<Player/>}/> 
          </Routes>
        </div>
      );
    }
    
    export default App;
```

Comment: why not preventing to rerun the code in useEffect based on your condition?

Comment: Could you eleborate? It seems that my dispatch in the useffect updates the state, and that makes it rerun and render the Player component twice

Comment: Can you create a sample here https://codesandbox.io/s/new?file=/src/App.js and share the link in the question. It will be easier to debug

Comment: what's your code inside useEffect which shouldn't run twice?

Comment: My code is fetching data of a player in useEffect. So it runs twice. Right now it just console logs in useEffect but when I tested with an api call it fetches data twice and lags stufff

Comment: You are changing the DOM in your `App` component on the basis of the `user` object, which causes `App` to re-render, which in turn might be causing `Player` to re-render

Comment: Player is 100% rerendering because the dispatch operation updates the state, and cause App to load twice, causing Player to load twice with it. My question now and what I need help with is how to handle this so Player does not render again after dispatch

Comment: Try moving the logout button inside `player` component and remove it from App.js. So that App.js is constant

Comment: Makes no difference, not sure that’s how components work

Answer (score 0):

It's because there's two return statement in App component.
In your case, Player component is not rerendered, it's just switched to other Player component because you returned another element on the user's existence in your App component.

To solve the problem, you have to return one element whether user exists or not.

Here's my code.

```js
function App() {
    console.log("app component")
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const user = useSelector(state => state.user)

    useEffect(() => {
        const loggedUserJSON = window.localStorage.getItem('loggedUser')
        if (loggedUserJSON) {
            const user = JSON.parse(loggedUserJSON)
            dispatch(loginUser(user))
        }
    }, [])


    return (
        <div>
            {user && <h1><button onClick={() => dispatch(logoutUser())}>LOG OUT</button></h1>}
            <Routes>
                <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
                <Route path="/" element={<Login />} />
                <Route path="/player/:username" element={<Player />} />
            </Routes>
        </div>
    );
}
```

In this code, Route component is the same component, not a new one and the props hasn't changed, so it won't be rerendered.
And you have to implement changing of the view of Login component on the user existence, because this logic belongs to Login component, not App component.

Comment: Hi, I have sadly tried this already and it still rerenders <Player/> twice. Again, it seems that the dispatch in useffect no mattr what causes App to rerender entirely again, this rerendering components like <Player /> or <Login/> again, so twice

Comment: I thought it would work and I don't still understand why it's not working. Don't Player component relies on user state? If so, it's natural for Player Component to be rendered twice.

Comment: Anyway, there's still a way. You can set user data extracted from local storage as a default state in user reducer not in App component. I think getting user data from local storage is needed only once while initializing so it won't cause problems.